# Toggle between two elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="test">
<span class="one">Alias</span>
<span class="two">Bobby</span>
<span class="show"><input type="text" value="Bobby"><br>  <button>Save</button></span>
<span class="three">Edit</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible with CSS, that when I click on the `test div` to hide `span two` and show `span show` and maybe change Edit to Close?

If not how do I achieve this?

I thought :focus was the thing but it wasnt.  Here is in example of what i want but only show if you click on it:

https://jsfiddle.net/g9bwbw3d/

Comment: i have no idea what you're trying to say here

Comment: With jquery this isn't all that hard. Look into it :)

Comment: This is not possible with CSS, because you need JS to handle the click event.

Comment: Hi, This link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127618/how-can-i-toggle-a-div-to-reveal-content-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're searching for :active selector.
of curse its not powerful as js.
check this out

https://jsfiddle.net/59ae3jmq/2/

```
<div id="test" class="test">
    <span class="one">Alias</span>
    <span class="two">Bobby</span>
    <span class="show"><input type="text" value="Bobby"><br><a href="#top"><button>Save</button></a></span>
    <a href="#test" class="three">Edit</a>
</div>
```

```
.test { display: flex; line-height: 35px; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; ;pointer:default;outline:none}
.test span { flex: 1;}

.test .show { display: none; }

.test:target > .two { display: none; }
.test:target > .show { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with jQuery.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oqtgbhkv/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('.three').on('click', function() {
        $('span.two').css('display', 'none');
        $('span.show').css('display', 'block');  
        $('span.three').css('display', 'none');
        $('input[name="name"]').val($('span.two').html());
    });

  $('span button').on('click', function() {
    $('span.two').css('display', 'block');
    $('span.show').css('display', 'none');  
    $('span.three').css('display', 'block');
    $('span.two').html($('input[name="name"]').val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Jquery you can do something like this:

```
$('.test').bind('click', function() {
    $('.two').hide();
    $('.show').show();
    $('.three').text('Close');
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jltorresm/q61mv800/2/